# Summing on multiple attribute value on same coordinate in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, coordinates, geolocation, summarizing

I have data like this:

[image]

If we see clearly then there is same data in same coordinate, now I am doing manually like this picture which is very time-consuming.

[image]

How can do it easily in QGIS?

Comment: Why don't you do it in Excel using [`sumif`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)?

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 8):

1. [Load your CSV](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/opening_data.html#importing-a-delimited-text-file)
2. Run ["Aggregate"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#aggregate) from QGIS's Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

   As a group by expression use, `geom_to_wkt($geometry)`

   *Note:* only `$geometry` may not work and as aggregate function on your field choose `sum`.

   [image]

Comment: concatenating Lon and Lat as Group by expression should also work, so only attribute based, even without having any geometries.